# QTableWidget colors, styles

Tags: qt, colors, grid, qtablewidget

I'm quite new to Qt and I'd appreciate the ability to customize a QTableWidget. I found a nice CSS-like interface using the stylesheets as shown here

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtablewidget

However, I need to change some more specific styles (like grid color, items background color and so on).

I couldn't find any documentation describing the properties that might be changed via stylesheets.

Thanks for any help.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks, it helped a bit...however i still missed some other properties as grid thickness, but i "solved" it by inserting a row/column with 1px height/width to double the gridline :) And the QTableWidgetItem::setBackgroundColor() was also helpful.

However, I'm still facing some issues with **QTableWidgetItem**, the text keeps hiding if the column is too slim...only 3 dots appear.  Dont you have an idea? I need the text to be visible, even if a bit clipped, but from the problem definition I cannot resize the column.

Comment: Look for QStyleOptionViewItem::textElideMode in the documentation. The exact usage depends on your implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't 
http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties
the list you are looking for?